# Change numbering in parts

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to start sectioning with 1 instead of 0.

I start with subsections, but they start with 0.1 and 0.2 and 0.2.1 - for example - I want it to start with 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you are using the `article` (or similar) class you need a `\section` before a `\subsection`. If you are using the `book` (or similar) class you need a `\chapter` before the `\section`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Even with the use of \section, it still starts with 0

Comment: Then you _probably_ has a `book`-based class (`report`, for example). In this case try adding a `\chapter`. If that doesn't work, please post a compilable minimal example of your document which reproduces the wrong numbering.

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: i use report as class